# How to get the last row using MYSQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

have two tables, table sets and chapters with MySQL table:

### Table Series

ID_SERIES

NAME

DESCRIPTION

---

### Table Chapters

ID_CHAPTERS

ID_SERIES

VIDEO

DATE_CREATED

---

As I can group all the chapters by id and give me back that I return in the last chapter, that way I do this query ?

thanks for reading.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Also what have you tried? Post some code...

Comment: I need everything id_video group and each group to show me the latest: SELECT * FROM VIDEOS LEFT JOIN CHAPTER ON VIDEOS.ID_VIDEO = CHAPTER.ID_VIDEO GROUP BY CHAPTER .ID_VIDEO ORDER BY CHAPTER.DATE_CREATED DESC;

Comment: Even I returned the first chapter

Comment: I don't understand what you are writing - please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your last comment your SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM VIDEOS 
    LEFT JOIN CHAPTER ON VIDEOS.ID_VIDEO = CHAPTER.ID_VIDEO 
GROUP BY CHAPTER .ID_VIDEO 
ORDER BY CHAPTER.DATE_CREATED DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

The `LIMIT 1` makes the query return just 1 row.

Comment: So that I can better understand what I want in my program is:

Show the last videos posted in each series with your date using the two tables (series, and video) in one sql query.